# iOS - How to replace the Local sqliteDB that already exists

Tags: ios, sqlite

I use sqlite db as local storage in users device. Now we have some changes in DB and I want to reflect that in User's DB. How can I do that?

Previously, I updated the DBVersion and checked in the code and used UserDefaults to save the condition. Now I don't want to create new key in UserDefaults.I want to know a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the key in the database?

Check the value of the key and if it's not the expected value then run your database update procedures and the update the value of the key in the database?

It makes a bit more sense to me to store the key value as part of the database instead of an external value.